# Better pythonic way to handle very big python nested defaultdict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, out-of-memory, defaultdict

I am constructing a nested defaultdict data structure like below:

```
mydata = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(
    lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))))))
```

when processing a big file line by line.  For each line processing, I do the following:

```
mydata[level_1][level_2][level_3][level_4][level_5][level_6] += 1
```

After the file processing is done, I then loop through the nested mydata dict to do further summarization.  The problem is when the file is too big, the dict will use all the memory and becomes infeasible.  Could you please point me to a better solution for this problem?

Comment: Is it feasible to use tuples `(level_1, level_2, ... level_6)` as keys in a flat `defaultdict`, in stead of using a nested structure? If not, it might help if you explained your use case briefly.

Comment: Needs more info for sure. The nesting of dicts isn't going to take up particularly much space, dicts are small objects. The issue is the data is eating up the memory, not the dicts themselves. What specifically are you doing? How big of a file are you processing?

Comment: @myrtlecat, Alexander:  Thank you for your reply.  The file could be as big as 100 gb with 300+ million lines.  What I am trying to do is to count items at every level and write them out to a csv file.  For example, how many items at level_1, how many items at level_2 for each item at level_1....., and so forth, and all the way to the last level.  If I put all the information from such a big file into this giant dict, it will eat up all the memory.  I am wondering if there are better ways that I don't have to store all the data into memory but can still quickly query them at each level.

Comment: We will need more details to be of help I think. What format is the data in? Is the file a CSV maybe, or something else? Can you show us a sample of it? What are the range of possible values for `level_1`, `level_2` etc?